# How to get the image path as soon as user opens it from phone gallery?

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have to implement an app which uploads the image on the server as soon as the user opens any of his/her images from the phone gallery section.My question is how to get the image path? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: i hv'nt got any solution yet..no idea

Comment: Yes, you don't have a solution. But have you at least tried using something? Googling for it? Or do you want us to give you complete code?

Comment: yes i want you to give me the complete commented code...if you cant den dont panic dear...your time out :)

Comment: @Ishant see the solution I have posted that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First call this intent to pick image from gallery :

```
private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;

Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

When you are done with select image from gallery it will automatically call this `onActivityResult` method :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PHOTO:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                try {
                    yourImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(selectedImage));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will get image path in `selectedImage` variable.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for this and iam aware of it...but my scenario is different.I want a background app for me to do this or some kind of broadcast receiver which triggers on native gallery selection from android mobile.